# Absolute positioning changing

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a carousel of images that rotates, when you click one, it "pops up" using jQuery, heres how:

```
var $img = $(event.target);
        $('#popUp').html($img.clone().height(200).width(300)).add($('#overLay')).fadeIn();
        $('#popUp').add($('#overLay')).click(function () {
        $('#popUp').add($('#overLay')).fadeOut(function () {
        $('#popUp').empty();
```

This works great, except the popUp div changes locations depending on which image is clicked (all images the same size) and only centers correctly one one of the clicked images.

The CSS used to accomplish the positioning is:

```
#popUp
 {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px; 
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Parent element style:

```
#carousel1
{
width:1000px;
height:200px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Is it possible to set this up so that no matter which image is clicked, they all appear centered in the screen?

Comment: It's being positioned based off of it's parent's relative position, can you provide the parent's styles too?

Comment: Subtract image width from window width divided by two. Do the same with height. do `$('#popUp').css({top: h, width: w});`.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock could you structure your comment as an answer, and maybe explain the "window" width?

Comment: Like a lightbox, you mean? Are you open to pre-made options, such as [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demonstration of Concept

Here is one way you might approach this problem using jQuery.

I am going to demonstrate how to create a popup window (centered horizontally and vertically with respect to the view port) to view an enlarged image. I also create an overlay that partially obscures the remainder of the screen.

For example, your HTML could be as follows:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/220/220">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/230/230">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/240/240">
</div>
<div class="popup"></div>
```

I will explicitly define an element (initially hidden) that will sever as the popup/overlay.

The CSS would resemble the following:

For the `.carousel`, I have a set of inline-block images text-aligned in the center of the parent container:

```
.carousel {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto; /* set this to 1000px and see how it behaves with scrolling */
}
.carousel img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For the popup/overlay:

```
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(125,125,125,0.5);
}
.popup .wrap {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
.popup .wrap img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The `.popup` element is positioned fixed and sized to fill the viewport (window).  I have an inner wrapper container (`.wrap`) of fixed width and height, which is positioned absolutely with respect to the fixed positioned parent.  I adjusted the left/top margins to center it.

The image is scaled so that the height fills the `.wrap` element, and because of `text-align: center` on the `.wrap`, the image is centered horizontally.

Finally, the jQuery:

```
function showPopup(imgSrc) {
    var theImg = '<div class="wrap"><img src="'+imgSrc+'"></div>';
    $(".popup").empty().append(theImg).fadeIn();
}

$(".carousel img").on('click',function (){
    var theSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    showPopup(theSrc);
});
$(".popup").on('click', ".wrap", function(){
    $(".popup").fadeOut();
})
```

When you click on a thumbnail, the popup/overlay fades in, and fades out when you click on the image or the left/right white space around it.

You can see a working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rQdZR/

**Other Comments**

You can develop several variations around this demo, for example, you can leave out the
overlay so that you can click on the thumbnails directly.  You can also fix the position where the popup will appear other than the center of the view port.

Answer (score 0):

vertical align?

http://jsfiddle.net/UTXL4/

```
#popUp{
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-right:-200px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color:red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Same issue with fixed position

Comment: did you want it centering on the page or centering inside the carousel div?